# When to use NSMutableDictionary instead of NSMapTable?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary, foundation

NSMapTable seems like a much more powerful and flexible cousin of NSMutableDictionary.  It can be configured to work in NSMutableDictionary (to copy keys and keep strong reference of value) In what circumstances should I not use NSMapTable?

Comment: Mainly, there are a lot more ways to shoot yourself in the foot with NSMapTable, and it's unnecessary complexity for 99.9% of uses.

Comment: Also, it's not clear that NSMapTable is "plug compatible" with NSMutableDictionary, so you likely would not be able to use it in many cases, and would be constantly switching back and forth.

Comment: Mattt Thompson (of NSHipster) has [a good article about it here](http://nshipster.com/nshashtable-and-nsmaptable/)

Comment: @HotLicks How do you shoot yourself in the foot with NSMapTable?

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer `NSDictionary` (and `NSSet`) in 99% of the cases. More abstraction means only bigger complexity and more ways to make an error.

I would use `NSMapTable` (and `NSHashTable`) only in one case - to store weak references.
I can't see any other good use for them.

Comment: @Boon Regular `CFDictionary`. Quoting `NSMapTable` docs: _...typically you are encouraged to use the C function API for void * pointers..._ Or I will just wrap it in a `NSValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that NSMapTable sometimes not deallocates keys and objects if weak-weak, weak-strong or strong-weak bindings are used http://cocoamine.net/blog/2013/12/13/nsmaptable-and-zeroing-weak-references/.

Also in NSMapTable.h you can find that **'entries are not necessarily purged right away when the weak key is reclaimed'** :

```
+ (id)weakToStrongObjectsMapTable NS_AVAILABLE(10_8, 6_0); 
// entries are not necessarily purged right away when the weak key is reclaimed
+ (id)weakToWeakObjectsMapTable NS_AVAILABLE(10_8, 6_0); 
// entries are not necessarily purged right away when the weak key or object is reclaimed
```